# How to summarize error messages of an emerge run?

Tags: logs, gentoo, emerge

An update on a gentoo system with

```
# emerge --update --newuse --deep --keep-going @world
```

creates lots of text on the console. 
Error messages and warnings appear between less important informative lines of the compiler.

**Which tools help to summarize the problems of the last update runs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [app-portage/elogviewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elogviewer/). It has a GUI in which you can sort, filter and flag the messages.
[image: elogviewer]

There is also a curses based tool called [app-portage/elogv](https://github.com/gentoo/elogv) in case you want to stay on the command line.

Note that in both cases you need to enable and select elogs in your `make.conf`. You get all the information with:

```
PORTAGE_ELOG_SYSTEM="save"
PORTAGE_ELOG_CLASSES="warn error info log qa"
```

You can deactivate some of the information in case it is never helpful.

Also note that this does not save the whole build log. If a program fails to compile you will still have to emerge it again to see where the problem is.